# Is it normally for Apple employees to ask to log out of iCloud (and disable find my) for repairs?

Tags: icloud, repair, applecare

My MacBook needed repairs and the employee asked to log out of iCloud. I did and when I got my laptop repaired and back, I now have two MacBooks registered on my account in the Apple Store. They replaced the logic board, but I wondering about the old logic board and I am wondering if logging out of iCloud was necessary and if I can trust them with my old logic board and if they can access personal data on there?

Comment: They need you to log out of icloud so they can reboot it and enter administrator mode without needing your credentials

Comment: It's better for your privacy if someone else has a device that _isn't_ attached to your cloud account than one that is.

Answer (score 6):

Trust is more about your threat model and risk than the policy they train to IMO.

- [Can I trust Apple support and share my password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223974/)
- [Can I trust Apple Store's employees with my laptop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72417/)

Here are some observations:

- Apple Service employees are trained in privacy and data protection. They do have access to sales and service records. This access is logged and audited regularly. Apple has a history of weeding out rogue employees that don’t care about the rules (which is of no solace to anyone whose trust does get abused or privacy violated).
- Signing out of iCloud and find my removes the activation lock functionality that is critical for a logic board swap to progress smoothly while in the shop.
- Your storage contains all data - the logic board does not store files or personal data past what they already had available (which is the unique ID of the logic board or network hardware adapters).
- Service employees can not look up your password - you have to give it to them.
- Service employees have the tools, training and opportunity to copy and retain all data you deliver to them.
- You can encrypt and erase the data - steps vary - ask them about how to know and learn this *before* you make a decision what to hand off to service staff.
- It looks like they followed all the steps for service - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209095

My experience is Apple support goes out of their way to educate you if you ask. They have service records with the old and new serial, so I wouldn’t worry much. Change your password if you gave it to them and study up before the next repair so you don’t have nagging doubt you made an error. I don’t think you did, but it’s hard to tell based on no details of macOS version, hardware type and what you chose to secure your Mac and what passwords (if any) you provided to them.